# How to delete columns or reorder using column number reference, not column name Python Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm new to python spark having only just started in python, so aplogies if this question is really dim

How do I delete columns or reorder my python spark dataframe using column number refs, not column names? My col names are long and I have a lot of cols, using names is v tedious

I want to turn eg:

```
 Data = Data.drop("070_thing", "230_anglething", "152_magnetthing", "200_status_thing", "155_thing")
```

into:

```
  Data = Data.drop(1, 5, 9, 15, 22)
```

Also reorder, so instead of:

```
 df = df.select("id","name","time","city")
```

I want to put:

```
 df = df.select(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use df.columns:

```
columns = Data.columns
Data.select(columns[0], columns[1])
```

or:

```
  from operators import itemgetter

  df_getter = lambda cols: list(itemgetter(**cols, columns))
  data.select(*df_getter((1, 2, 3)))
```